# Match who objects ObjectId to use their "matching" data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

(sorry for my fantastic drawing with only the colour red)

I have two objects:

**The "Driver" object**
[image]

**And the "Carrier" object**
[image]

In my React application I can display all of the properties in the **driver** object, but I also want the **image** from the **carrier** object.

(Sorry if this looks messy). Here's what I currently do with all the other data I'm fetching:

```
const event = this.props.events || []
const lock = this.props.locks || []
const customer = this.props.customers || []
const driver = this.props.drivers || []
const carriers = this.props.carriers || []

const keyedCustomers = _.keyBy(customer, '_id')
const keyedDrivers = _.keyBy(driver, '_id')
const keyedLocks = _.keyBy(lock, '_id')

const keyedCarriers = _.keyBy(carriers, 'image')

const events = event.slice(0, this.state.showCount).map((event, i) => {
  return (
    <EventItem
      key={i}
      event={event}
      customer={keyedCustomers[event.customer]}
      carriers={keyedCarriers[event.driver]}
      driver={keyedDrivers[event.driver]}
      lock={keyedLocks[event.unit] || { address: {} }}
    />
  )
})
```

And later just using it inside of that child's component:

```
    export default class EventItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const { event, customer, driver, lock, carriers } = this.props
    const isCustomer = !customer
    const person = customer || driver

    return (
      <div>
        <Row style={{ marginTop: '-10px' }}>
          <Col md={12}>
            <ul className="events-list">
              <li className="events-flex-container">
                <div className="events-flex-item-1">
                  <h5 className="events-title-text">
                    {isCustomer ? `HEJSAN` : null} {person.name}
                    {`${person.name} ${person.surname} öppnade ${lock.custom_name} på ${lock
                      .address.street}`}
                  </h5>
                  <p className="events-sub-title-text">
                    {moment(`${event.timestamp}`).format(
                      'MM/D [klockan] HH:mm'
                    )}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </Col>
        </Row>
```

)

**My Question**

Since the **driver** object contains the key `carrier` with the **same** `objectId` as the **carrier** object, but with the key `_id` can I map over these objects and the pick out the `image` url from **carrier** and these props as "one" object.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter carriers by id and can get the image from the filtered carrier.

```
const carrier = carriers.filter((carrier) => (carrier._id === driver.carrier));
```

Also as I can see from your image you are using MongoDB. You can try to use `db.aggregate(...)` try to populate results as you desire.

Another approach cab be that you can add carrier.image to driver object for a more easy to reach option. This option also adds some more database storage that you should consider of course.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I really like your way to solve it, but when having this line in my code; `const carrier = carriers.filter(carrier => carrier._id === driver.carrier)` I get the error: `Cannot read property 'carrier' of undefined`.

Comment: Can you show me the `console.log(driver);` output and also show me where did you add the snippet that I sent?

Comment: `driver` seems to be undefined, but that is because I have a "Show more" button and when pressing that button more list items will render out and `driver` stops being undefined because it's now fetching `driver` data. 

I added that snippet in the `EventItem` component after my consts.

Comment: Ok so the error is caused by driver being undefined. Can't really understand why it is since I can't see your complete code, checking if the driver is undefined before trying to get carrier is can be the best approach. Also another approach can be if the drivers array is filled on parent component you can loop through them with forEach and append image from the filtered carrier to the object

Comment: I created a gist! if you could take a look I would be really happy.
https://gist.github.com/Martinnord/d93a8f89490b815c1ff1198ccd1d4b04

Comment: I sent a comment on your gist. I would appreciate if you consider setting my post as answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot mister. Now I'm getting the stuff in my console. The last step is to being able to match the `carrier.image` with the correct driver. I tried something like this: 
`<h5 className="events-title-text">
  {isCustomer ? `Förare ${carrier.image}` : null}
  {person.name}
  {`${person.name} ${person.surname} öppnade ${lock.custom_name} på ${lock
    .address.street}`}
</h5>` but I'm getting undefined.